# Joining two result sets into one

Tags: cassandra, union, resultset, cql

I wanted to know if there's a way to join two or more result sets into one.
  I actually need to execute more than one query and return just one result set. I can't use the UNION or the JOIN operators because I'm working with Cassandra (CQL)
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Framework like Playorm provide support for JOIN (INNER and LEFT JOINs)queries in Cassandra.

http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Command-Line-Tool/

You may see more examples at:

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/master/src/test/java/com/alvazan/test/TestJoins.java

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Excuse me but first I want to ask a question that is a little bit out of topic. In TestJoins.java they're using aliases in queries, is that possible with Cassandra ?!

Comment: Playorm parses the queries at its end and support aliases.  Visit this link for more information http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Fast-Scalable-Queries/ and http://buffalosw.com/products/playorm/ for Playorm's complete feature list.

Answer (score 3):

If your wanting to query multiple rows within the same column family you can use the IN keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM testCF WHERE key IN ('rowKeyA', 'rowKeyB', 'rowKeyZ') LIMIT 10;
```

This will get you back 10 results from each row.

If your needing to join results from different CFs, or query with differing WHERE clauses, then you need to run multiple queries and merge the results in code - cassandra doesn't cater for that kind of thing.

Comment: Actually I want to implement the Union operator, so I need to join results from different column families that have the same architecture. I'm wondering if I can have one result set that contains the results of all the column families ?

Answer (score 2):

PlayOrm can do joins, but you may need to have PlayOrm partitioning on so you still scale.  (ie. you dont' want to join 1 billion rows with 1 billion rows).  Typically instead you do a join of one partition with another partition or a partition on the Account table joining a partition on the Users table.  ie. make sure you design for scale still.